# How to compute upper bound for the absolute and relative error of an expression

Tags: python, math

Let's say I have an expression such as a − πb / π^2 + b, where the value of a is approximately 1.21, approximated value of b 1.9 and π 3.14.

How could I compute upper bound for the absolute and relative error for the entire expression in python?

I have not been able to find any function or method to do this.

Comment: So a and π are off by up to +/-0.01, and b is off by up to +/-0.1?  And you want to know the bounds for the entire expression?

Comment: Exactly @Mark Ransom

Comment: Hi @Mark Ransom, yes, for the entire expression. Although, I think that given that these are rounding approximations, a and π would have an error of 0.05, and b of 0.5.

Comment: So the true value of a will be between 1.16 and 2.26?  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: I mean, assuming rounding approximations, and given that we have rounded a to 1.21, we had numbers ranging from 1.205 1.21499..., which yields an absolute error for this rounding approximation of 0.005 (that's the maximum error we could have in this case). So yes, I was wrong in my previous comment. We consider that a and π would have an error of 0.005, and b of 0.05. I think this is equivalent to the margins we mentioned in your first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the round() function.

Example:

```
round(1.4) -> 1
round(1.6) -> 2
round(1.9) -> 2
```

Comment: I am afraid that's not the bounds for the errors of the entire expression.